# File upload form element that will allow the user to select files from server

Tags: 8, forms, files

I want to achieve ([Create a form that will allow the user to select files from server](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/124152/create-a-form-that-will-allow-the-user-to-select-files-from-server?rq=1)) in Drupal 8.3 and have followed steps 1 to 4 but for some reason it's not working at my end.

Can someone shed light how code can be updated in Drupal 8.3 to achieve above?

Thanks

Comment: I dont know the exact code to be used for ur scenario. but i was referred the attached link in your question. some of the methods are depreciated in drupal 8 . like drupal_add_js . Please refer below link. so you will get some idea. https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-8-module and also hook_menu is depreciated in drupal 8. All route configuration is done via **routing. yml.file** Below links may helpfull to you.
https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/routing-system/structure-of-routes

Comment: Thanks but I already know above ref links and have successfully attached js. But my problem still remains unresolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have achieved this in version 8.3 by enabling IMCE module and with the following logic i.e

1)

```
<script>
  function imageFileSelector() {
    window.open('/imce?urlField=edit-image-file-path-1', '', 'width=760,height=560,resizable=1');
  }
</script>
```

'edit-image-file-path-1' is id value for form field 'image_file_path_1'.

2)

```
$form['image_file_selector'] = array(
  '#markup' => t("<br /><b>Image File *</b><br><a onclick=imageFileSelector();>Click to choose Image File</a><br>"),
);
$form['image_file_path_1'] = array(
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#attributes' => array('readonly' => 'readonly'),
  '#default_value' => $result->image_file_path_1,
);
```